# Simple create an object in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, object

I have two function one is get data from DB:

```
       $data['article']=$this->Marticle->get_article_where($id);
```

and after an data path to view. Part of data are data for title and description tags.

In another function I would like send  tag and description to the same view manually.
For this I created an object:

```
   $this->article = new stdClass();
         $data['article'][0]->title='how to create an object in Ci';
         $data['article'][0]->description='This article will help with creating...:)';
```

and then I get error "Message: Creating default object from empty value"
I know that is just notice and how I can disable it. Also I read related topic, however there was suggestion to create Class. Is simple way to resolve this task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not want this error try this :

```
 $data['article'] = array();

 $data['article'][0] = new stdClass();
 $data['article'][0]->title='how to create an object in Ci';
 $data['article'][0]->description='This article will help with creating...:)';

 $data['article'][1] = new stdClass();
 //$data['article'][1]->title = ...
```

But i did not understand why `$this->article`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help:

```
$data['article']=$this->Marticle->get_article_where($id)->result();
echo "<pre>";print_r( $data['article'] );die;
```

The `->result()` will return the object and `->result_array()` will return array.

Comment: No, no, I know how acces data in result array. I need create same $data['article'] object array. Look to the second code part.